# A consequence of Dedekind's independence theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I first remind Dedekind's independence theorem

> Let $G$ be a group and $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ characters of $G$ to
>   a field $L$ that are $2$ by $2$ different. Then
>   $\{\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n\}$ is a linearily independent set over
>   $L$.

Where

> A character $\sigma$ of $G$ to $L$ is a group morphism $\sigma$ from
>   $G$ to the multiplicative group $L^*$.

and

> A set of characters $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ of $G$ to $L$ is called
>   linearilly independent if $$a_1\sigma_1 + \cdots a_n\sigma_n = 0$$
>   implies that $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$

Apparently a consequence of this is the fact that distinct ring homomorphisms of a field $K$ into a field $F$ are linearily independent over $F$.

I don't get this.

Indeed, ring homomorphisms are not from $(K^*,\cdot)$ to $(F^*,\cdot)$ so we don't fit into the setting of Dedekind's theorem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it fit? Ring homomorphisms from $K$ to $F$ are also group homomorphisms from $K^*$ to $F^*$, no?

Comment: @tomak of course You consider ring homomorphisms that map identity element to identity element i.e. $\phi:K\rightarrow F$ fulfills $\phi(1_K)=1_F$ from which You get $\phi(k^{-1})=\phi(k)^{-1}$ for $k\in K^{*}$

Comment: Yes my bad. This works